# Ajax ModalPopupExtender positioning issue, not aligned in center

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modal-dialog, modalpopupextender

I am using Ajax toolkit and ModalPopExtender specifically, works fine, just have a big time issue with its positioning, I am using it to display images and all images have different height and width and hence some times it appears like bottom left of the screen with half of it going off the screen, I could have fixed it by specifying values for X and Y coordinates, but since the images sizes changes, if image is to small then user need to scroll the pointer all the way up.

The thing is it appears at a random location but as soon as I scroll or re size page, it relocates it self to the exact center of the screen (where its actually required).

Experts, kindly suggest a work around.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two potential solutions: 1) Preload all the images or make sure they have finished loading before showing the popup. 2) Handle the `load` events of every image and trigger the parent window's `resize` event when they all have finished loading.

Comment: There is one more solution and that is to change the scroll position every time the ModalPopup.Show() is called, but not able to implement it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no rigid solution to it, We contacted MSDN team as well, solved by replacing it with the Jquery Light Box.